# Comparing field values using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, field

I am trying to compare the field values of two different objects in a generic way. I have a function (seen below) that takes in two Objects and then gets the fields and then compares the fields in a loop and adds the fields to a list if they are not the same - is this the proper way to do this?

```
public void compareFields(Object qa, Object qa4) throws FieldsNotEqualException
{

  Field[] qaFields = qa.getClass().getFields();
  Field[] qa4Fields = qa4.getClass().getFields();

  for(Field f:qaFields) 
  { 

    for(Field f4:qa4Fields)
    {
       if(f4.equals(f))
       {
           found = true;
           break;
       }
       else
       {
           continue;
       }
    }
  }

 if(!found)
 {
    report.add(/*some_formatted_string*/) //some global list 
    throw new FieldsNotEqualException();
 }
}
```

I was googling and I saw that C# had like a PropertyInfo Class - does Java have anything like that?
ALSO, is there a way to do like `f.getFieldValue()` -I know there is no method like this but maybe there is another way???

Comment: Fields belong to classes, values are held (if not static) in instances. What exactly you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ok I should have been clearer - im passing in two instances of two objects - im trying to compare two data sets (lists of objects) that are being returned by hibernate - but I am passing them in a loop one instance of the object of some class at a time to compare the fields of that instance against some other instance

Comment: @JohH If you are using Hibernate, this approach might not work - Hibernate modifies the object contents at runtime and I am not sure that reflection will work - it might, but if you experience something funny, it could be Hibernate interfering with the object properties.

Comment: @RaviWallau I think at that point Hibernate is done interfering with those objects...I run a query and then get a List<Object>() back from hibernate. If I wanted to do it in a non generic way I could cast each of the instances in the list and then compare the values - but that would be a lot of code that could be done generically.

Comment: @JohH If you are using IntelliJ you can generate equals() and hashCode() automatically. I tend to like these more than using reflection to compare the data, as with reflection you can't limit the fields that will be compared.

Comment: Off topic - I see you just deleted a question. I hope you didn't let the negativity get to you, it was a valid question and you deserved a reasonable answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960118/64-bit-pointer-conversion

Comment: @MarkRansom I realized that I didn't fully understand the code prior to me asking the question - and once I did understand I figured that the question wasn't a very good question...and since it had gotten so much feedback that it would be best to delete it...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might check out org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder which will save you a lot of this hassle if you're wanting to do a field by field comparison.

```
org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(Object, Object)
```

If you're wanting to compare fields yourself, check out `java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields()` which will give you all the fields including non-public fields.

To compare the value of the fields use `f.get(qa).equals(f.get(qa4))`  Currently, you are actually comparing the field instances and not the values.

Comment: how does getDeclaredFields() help when i need to compare the values?

Comment: @JonH I updated my answer slightly.  The main point is that you really should consider a common library for doing this comparision.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok - I believe this is working - but I have a quick question - so o`f.get(qa)` will get field "some_name"'s value - so I dont have to worry about field ordering or making sure it is comparing the same field right?

Comment: Assuming these are the same class type, the field order will be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Libraries like [commons-beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) can help you if you want to compare bean properties (values returned by getters) instead of comparing field values.

However, if you want to stick with plain reflection, you should:

1. Use `Class.getDeclaredFields()` instead of `Class.getFields()`, as the latter only returns the public fields.
2. Since fields only depend on their class, you should cache the result and keep the fields in a static / instance variable rather than invoking `getDeclaredFields()` for each comparison.
3. Once you have an object of that class (say `o`), in order to get the value of some field `f` for that particular object, you need to call: `f.get(o)`.

Answer (score 0):

// If you want to have some fields, not all field then use this.

```
  public boolean compareObject(Object object) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException 
{

 String[] compareFields = { "fieldx", "fieldy","fieldz", "field15",
        "field19"}; // list of all we need 
for(String s : compareFields) {
Field field = DcrAttribute.class.getDeclaredField(s); // get a list of all fields for this class
    field.setAccessible(true);
    if(!field.get(this).equals(field.get(object))){  //if values are not equal          
    return true;    
    }       

    }

    return false;
}
```